# Set invisible/visible for button and process bar android

Tags: android

I created a simple widget and I want to change the button to process circle in 2 seconds. I tried to set for widget_button and pbHeaderProgress. But after 2 seconds, the button still display and the process bar does not. Please help me! Thanks in advance!
Here is my code:

```
private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(final Context context) {

        Log.e(TAG, "updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener");
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_demo);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_idiom, " ");
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_button, View.INVISIBLE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbHeaderProgress, View.VISIBLE);

        final Handler threadHandler = new Handler();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "okokok");
                        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbHeaderProgress,
                                View.INVISIBLE);
                        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_button,
                                View.VISIBLE);
                        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_idiom,
                                (CharSequence) getTextToShow());
                        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,
                                MyWidgetProvider
                                        .buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
                        MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(
                                context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);

                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="2sp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/widget_idiom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="right|bottom">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/widget_button_setting"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:background="@drawable/setting"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/widget_button_detail"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/detail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_button_setting"

        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/widget_button"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/refresh"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_button_detail"
        />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_button_detail"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you want the button should be `INVISIBLE` and the process bar should be `VISIBLE` after `2 Seconds`? right?

Comment: That's right! I want the button must be replaced by the process bar in 2 seconds (they have the same position in my layout).

Comment: I have tried your code that does this very well, `means` the button is gone and the progress bar is visible after 2 seconds.

Comment: I built it for Android 2.2. Could it take any effect to my program? The process bar was not be displayed. The button, however, was still be displayed. :(

Comment: I think that should not matter.!